# VBA - Rearranging Column Order Across Multiple Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 macros

1) Deletes columns (based on column headings) not specified in my array

Here is the code:

```
Sub testDelete()

Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("mySheet")

ws1.Activate

    With ws1

    For currentColumn = ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

        columnHeading = ws1.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

        'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
        Select Case columnHeading
            Case "Employee Number", "Status"
                'Do nothing
            Case Else

                    ws1.Columns(currentColumn).Delete

        End Select
    Next

    End With

End Sub
```

2) Reorders the columns on a specific worksheet and deletes whichever columns I did not specify in the array.

Here is the code:

```
Sub testReorder()

    Dim arrColOrder As Variant, ndx As Integer
    Dim Found As Range, Counter As Integer
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("mySheet")

    ws1.Activate

    arrColOrder = Array("Employee Number", "Status")

    'Copy and Paste Sheet as Values
    ws1.Cells.Copy
    ws1.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    With ws1

        Counter = 1

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        For ndx = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)

            Set Found = Rows("1:1").Find(arrColOrder(ndx), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not Found Is Nothing Then
                If Found.Column <> Counter Then
                    Found.EntireColumn.Cut
                    Columns(Counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End If
                Counter = Counter + 1
            End If
        Next ndx

        ws1.Range("K:M").EntireColumn.Delete

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End With

End Sub
```

Currently, these macros work great for one sheet only, however, when there's like 50 sheets, its not practical to name each one.

Most of the sheets will have the two column headings: *Employee Number* and *Status* and Some will only have *Employee Number*

What I am looking to do, is combine these macro's into one macro and allow it to work for all the sheets in the workbook, not just one.

This what I have so far:

```
Sub testNew()

    Dim Found As Range, Counter As Integer, ndx As Integer, currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String
    Dim arrColOrder As Variant

    arrColOrder = Array("Employee Number", "Status")

    'Copy and Paste Sheet as Values
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    For currentColumn = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.count To 1 Step -1

        columnHeading = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

        'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
        Select Case columnHeading
            Case "Employee Number", "Status"
                'Do nothing
            Case Else

                    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns(currentColumn).Delete

        End Select
    Next

    Counter = 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For ndx = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)

            Set Found = Rows("1:1").Find(arrColOrder(ndx), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not Found Is Nothing Then
                If Found.Column <> Counter Then
                    Found.EntireColumn.Cut
                    Columns(Counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End If
                Counter = Counter + 1
            End If
        Next ndx

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you approach it from another angle? You know the individual functions work. Create a wrapper function that loops through the collection of sheets and for each sheet calls the two functions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @sunsetsurf. I do not know how to do what you mentioned, would you be able to provide me with a sample code that can do what you mentioned perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution to my question.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ManipulateSheets()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim a As Long, w As Long
    Dim keepCols As Variant

    Set wkbk1 = Workbooks("3rd Party.xlsm")

    keepCols = Array("Employee Number", "Status")

    wkbk1.Activate

    For Each ws1 In wkbk1.Sheets

        ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="USERID", Replacement:="Employee Number", Lookat:=xlWhole
        ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="STATUS", Replacement:="Status", Lookat:=xlWhole
        ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="USER_ID", Replacement:="Employee Number", Lookat:=xlWhole
        ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="USER_STATUS", Replacement:="Status", Lookat:=xlWhole
        ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="HR_STATUS", Replacement:="Status", Lookat:=xlWhole

    Next ws1

    With wkbk1

        For w = 1 To .Worksheets.count

            With Worksheets(w)

                For a = .Columns.count To 1 Step -1

                    If UBound(Filter(keepCols, .Cells(1, a), True, vbTextCompare)) < 0 Then _
                            .Columns(a).EntireColumn.Delete

                Next a

            End With

        Next w

    End With

End Sub
```